# Ruby on Rails - Passing variables to a partial within a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

I am passing a collection (@feed_items) to a _feed_item partial via the :collection option. Inside the **_feed_item** partial I want to render another partial **_like_button**. In the **_like_button** partial I want to be able to access a specific member of the collection.  What should I be passing from the **_feed_item** partial to the **_like_button** partial?

```
 @feed_items = current_user.user_feed.order("id DESC").limit(5)
```

**_feed.html.erb**

```
 <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>
```

**_feed_item.html.erb**

```
 <%= render 'likes/like_button', ????? %>
```

**_like_button.html.erb**

```
 <% if like = current_user.likes.find_by_feed_id(feed_item.id) %>
```

**EDIT**

Passing the local variable as per the answers below worked:

```
 <%= render :partial => 'likes/like_button', :locals =>{:feed_item => feed_item} %>
```

However, after the like is submitted, I am getting a `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method 'feed_item'` when it tries to render the form again through ajax. How can I pass the local variable again through the ajax call?

**Controller**

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @like = Like.create(params[:like])
    @feed = @like.feed
    render :toggle
  end

  def destroy
    like = Like.find(params[:id]).destroy
    @feed = like.feed
    render :toggle
  end
end
```

**toggle.js.erb**

```
 $("#like").html("<%= escape_javascript render('like_button') %>");
```

**_like_button.html.erb**

```
 <% if like = current_user.likes.find_by_feed_id(feed_item.id) %>
  <%= form_for like, :html => { :method => :delete }, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit "Unlike" %>
  <% end %>
 <% else %>
  <%= form_for current_user.likes.build(:feed_id => feed_item.id), :remote => true do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :feed_id %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
   <%= f.submit "Like" %>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

**_feed_item.html.erb**

```
    <div id="like">
      <%= render :partial => 'likes/like_button', :locals =>{:feed_item => feed_item} %>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 <%= render :partial => 'likes/like_button', :locals =>{:feed_item => feed_item} %>
```

Rails has got some awesome documention http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables

In toggle.js

```
 $("#like").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'likes/like_button', :locals =>{:feed_item => @feed}) %>");
```

Comment: Thank you. That works (the database is updating), however I am still getting an error in the console `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method 'feed_item' for #<#<Class:0x00000102f6b078>:0x0000010452f7d8>)`. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: add the whole trace check which file it has been traversing through

Comment: may be you are calling it from any other form and the locals needs to be passed from there as well

Comment: The error is actually happening when it is rendering the form again through the ajax call. `Rendered likes/_like_button.html.erb (17.3ms)
  Rendered likes/create.js.erb (18.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method 'feed_item' for #<#<Class:0x000001046b46f8>:0x00000105c71f68>):
    1: <% if like = current_user.likes.find_by_feed_id(feed_item.id) %>
    2:  <%= form_for like, :html => { :method => :delete }, :remote => true do |f| %>
    3:   <%= f.submit "Unlike" %>
    4:  <% end %>`

Comment: This is my JavaScript Embedded Ruby file. How can I pass the local variable to this as well? `$("#like").html("<%= escape_javascript render('like_button') %>");`

Comment: render in same way like i answered here too , use locals and asssign appropriate object

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `feed_item` variable as a local to the `_like_button.html.erb` partial.

```
<%= render 'likes/like_button', :locals => { :feed_item => feed_item } %>
```

This just sets the local named `feed_item` in the inner partial to be whatever `feed_item` is in the outer partial.

Comment: Thank you. That works (the database is updating), however I am still getting an error in the console `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method 'feed_item' for #<#<Class:0x00000102f6b078>:0x0000010452f7d8>)`. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: create feed_item as an instance variable (@feed_item) and then use it in the inner partial with @feed_item instead of feed_item to avoid the error.

Answer (score 1):

When using collection to render the partial, so you wil be getting the local variable same as the render file name. So just you can pass the file name as a local variable.

For example if you have _feed_item.html.erb and you are rendering this partial using collection like

```
render "feed_item", collection: @feed_items
```

So you will be getting the feed_item local variable inside this feed_item partial.

So you can pass this feed_item variable as a local variable to another partial(in your case _like_button.html.erb)

Comment: Thank you. That works (the database is updating), however I am still getting an error in the console `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method 'feed_item' for #<#<Class:0x00000102f6b078>:0x0000010452f7d8>)`. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: where you give this "feed_item", can i know this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you have to do the following:

**_feed.html.erb**

```
 <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>
```

**_feed_item.html.erb**

Here you are defining a local variable called `feed_item` and assigment the value as each element of your collection. You can omit the word `locals` because Rails is smart enough to know that is an a `local` variable.

```
 <% @feed_items.each do |feed_item| %>
 <%= render 'likes/like_button', feed_item: feed_item %>
 <% end %>
```

**_like_button.html.erb**

```
 <% if like = current_user.likes.find_by_feed_id(feed_item.id) %>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am now having trouble rendering the form after an ajax update (see my edits to the question above). Do you know what might be going wrong?